# Print content between brackets in different lines

Tags: text-processing

How to print the content between two brackets.

For example:

```
return [ "server1.domain.com" ,

"server2.domain.com" ,

"server3.domain.com" ]
```

Expected result:

```
   "server1.domain.com" ,

   "server2.domain.com" ,

   "server3.domain.com"
```

How to get the expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -Mo 'return \[\K[^]]*'
```

<kbd>M</kbd>ultiline match on `return [` followed by a sequence of non-`]` characters but only <kbd>o</kbd>utput the part to <kbd>K</kbd>eep (to the right of `\K`).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. Is it possible to do this with grep command.

Comment: @manth, `pcregrep` is one of many `grep` implementations. Some other `grep` implementations like some versions of GNU `grep` will also work there if you replace the `pcregrep -Mo` with `grep -zPo` and pipe the output to `tr '\0' '\n'`

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`

```
sed '
    /.*\[ /{
        s///        #remove all upto open square bracket 
        :a          #return mark
        /\ ].*/!{
            N       #get next line untill there is close square bracket
            ba      #back to return mark
        }
        s///        #remove all from close square bracket to end of line 
     }
     '
```